# My android application isn't showing on main list of application. What I have to do?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-install-apk

I'm beginner of Android. I want to run my first application on emulator. I use eclipse.

I don't know what's happen. I installed my apk. I "register" my acitivity in manifest file, but I can't see it in list of application. When I open manage application setting it's written that my apk is installed. I searched about it everywhere.

Even in faq of Android Development there is post about but I did all this things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html) page:

> The first filter in the example — the
>   combination of the action
>   "android.intent.action.MAIN" and the
>   category
>   "**android.intent.category.LAUNCHER**" —
>   is a common one. It marks the activity
>   as one that should be represented in
>   the application launcher, the screen
>   listing applications users can launch
>   on the device. In other words, the
>   activity is the entry point for the
>   application, the initial one users
>   would see when they choose the
>   application in the launcher.

So to have your application in the application launcher, make sure you have **android.intent.category.LAUNCHER** set in the Manifest.

Comment: Greate answer! It's exactly what I was looking for. Thank!